# Django (1.11) ORM using postgresql query is not able to compare date

Tags: django, postgresql

Django (1.11) ORM using postgresql query is not able to compare date. I need data in between of `leave_date_from` and `leave_date_to`. 
I'm expecting one record.

My model is as follows:

```
class EmployeeLeaveApp(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.DO_NOTHING, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    leave_date_from = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    leave_date_to = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

My View query is :

```
inputdate = '2018-03-05'
duplicateleave = crm_models.EmployeeLeaveApp.objects.filter(
    leave_date_from__gte=inputdate,
    leave_date_to__lte=inputdate,
    user=user)
```

My table data is like below:

```
leave_date_from | leave_date_to | user
2018-03-01      | 2018-03-10    | 1
2018-03-07      | 2018-03-22    | 1
```

So far, I tried many solutions but no luck.

Comment: what are you getting now with this query?

Comment: No rows getting from this query. I should get one row

Comment: For this query you need two different dates to compare.

Comment: @sakthiselvam Why so? I need to check that input (date) is in between of particular record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime    
inputdate = datetime.strptime(inputdate, '%Y-%m-%d')    
duplicateleave = crm_models.EmployeeLeaveApp.objects.filter(
    leave_date_from__gte=inputdate,
    leave_date_to__lte=inputdate,
    user=user
)
```

==== OR ==== If error comes `must be str, not datetime.date` then use.

```
inputdate = datetime.strptime(str(inputdate), '%Y-%m-%d')
duplicateleave = crm_models.EmployeeLeaveApp.objects.filter(
    leave_date_from__gte=inputdate,
    leave_date_to__lte=inputdate,
    user=user
)
```

django expects a dateobject in the parameter, but you are passing string to it. so use this

Comment: Nope, not working. Though I tried this solution from SO.

Comment: how are you passing the user parameter? can you show that?

Comment: I'm using REST Framework, so I got error due to your solution, so I type casted that to date to str like `inputdate = datetime.strptime(str(inputdate), '%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: so are you getting data now?? and if not can you show your user value and how you are querying it?

Comment: Your part of solution got worked, please accept the edit, I'll except answer. Thanks.